# QT5 Combobox Right Click Causes Crash

Tags: c++, qt, combobox, qt5

The combobox has enough elements to include a scrollbar. Right clicking the scrollbar causes the program to crash.

I've tried installing an event filter and just stealing the event, but it doesn't work. Thoughts?

Comment: Just a thought, how is the ComboBox created? Perhaps setting a parent would help (something to do with widget containing widgets).

Comment: It's generated with the QT designer. Right now it's laid out in a QDialog. My filter didn't seem to capture the right click on the scrollbar that the combobox generated, so I think the problem is effectively with a widget generated by a widget anyway